# Removing raster's outline visible in exported document using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, outline

I work in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1.
I added a .tiff raster basemap to my project. Exported the layout as .tiff and when I opened the file in a image viewer there was an outline around the basemap tiff. It can't be seen in ArcGIS Pro environment. I made sure all background frames are disabled. I exported the .tiff with no background or outline yet it still appears.

What is causing this?

How can this be removed?

It can be seen as a thin grey frame (I uploaded only a part of the whole picture)

[image]

Here is the same picture taken directly in ArcGIS Pro environment - notice the outline isn't there.

[image]

Now I added grey background to the layout page and it highlighted the white background of the instered TIFF. Why does it make a grey outline when both backgrounds are white? Is there a way to remove this?
[image]

Comment: Are you applying some sort of mask to the map, e.g. masking by the administrative boundary?

Comment: No, I'm not. At least not that I know of. I didn't apply any masks or anything out of ordinary routine.